# Add ip link devices concurrently

Tags: iptables, ip

I need to add/delete ip link devices like bridge and tunnels concurrently with low latency.
Currently adding a tunnel, a bridge and connecting them at 5 TPS turns to be in seconds if some devices are getting deleted in parallel.

I use commands

```
sudo ip link add name bridge type bridge
```

What should be done to reduce the latency?

Comment: We can't recommend any alternatives as we don't know why you are doing this.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Huh? You didn't add anything to the question, you only removed something.